# Taylor series for $f(x)=\sin^2(x) \cdot \sqrt[4]{x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am not sure how to get the Taylor series of

$$\sin^2 (x)\cdot\sqrt[4]{x}$$

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. I tried turning the expression into MathJax formatted version, you can edit it if you like. For example if I made some mistake interpreting it.

Comment: The factor $x^{1/4}$ is not differentiable at $0$, which causes a problem for the development.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The term IS differentiable. It's not differentiable at $x = 0$. In any case he is asking for Taylor series, not McLaurin so...

Comment: @VonNeumann: anything wrong in my comment ?

Comment: @1999 you should provide at what point do you want to compute taylor series and number of terms in the series.

Comment: Around which point would you like to expand the Taylor series? You cannot expand around $x=0$ as @YvesDaoust noted above. How about $x=1$? Can you compute a couple fo first tmers?